# How can get length on checked checkbox array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
<form name='form1' >
   <input type=checkbox name='cbox[]' />
</form>

<script>    
   var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('ckbox[]')
   var ln = checkbox.length
   alert(ln)
</script>
```

How can I count only the checked checkboxes with JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Doing it with jQuery would shorten the code and make it more readable, maintainable and easier to understand. Use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L25NB/)**

```
$('[name="cbox[]"]:checked').length
```

Comment: Thank you all guys who helped me, I've used this solution :)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use plain javascript

```
var checkbox = document.getElementsByName('ckbox[]');
var ln = 0;
for(var i=0; i< checkbox.length; i++) {
    if(checkbox[i].checked)
        ln++
}
alert(ln)
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery solution:

```
var len = $("[name='cbox[]']:checked").length;
```

JavaScript solution:

```
var len = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[name='cbox[]']"))
    .filter(function(e) { return e.checked; }).length;
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('input:checked').length` will do if you do not have any other input tags than in this form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

jQuery solution:

```
var len = $(":checked",$("input[name='cbox[]']")).size();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fobj = document.forms[0];

var c = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < formobj.elements.length; i++)
{
if (fobj.elements[i].type == "checkbox")
{
if (fobj.elements[i].checked)
{
c++;
}
}       
}

alert('Total Checked = ' + c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out,

```
var boxes = $('input[name="cbox[]"]:checked');
```

find how many are checked,

```
$(boxes).size();
```

or

```
$(boxes).length();
```

Comment: Firstly, there is no need in wrapping jQuery object. Next, `size` method is deprecated, you should use `length` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = $("[name='cbox[]']:checked").length;
```

will work but will not work if you are directly comparing like

```
if ( $("[name='cbox[]']").length= $("[name='cbox[]']:checked").length)
```

Comment: Typo Consider it as if( $("[name='cbox[]'] ").length== $("[name='cbox[]']:checked").length)

Answer (score 0):

you also do by this

you have to define class for checkBox and then follow below

var chkLength = $('input.className:checked').length;
alert(chkLength);

this will print your total no of checkboxes from list

Answer (score 0):

You may use as below as well

```
$('[name=cbox\\[\\]]:checked').length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

var ch_n = $( "input:checked" ).length;